# how do i get link publishing cucumber report in java

Tags: java, cucumber-java

i just activate in my code

```
cucumber.publish.enabled = true
```

and the link has successfully generated

│ View your Cucumber Report at:                                            │

│ https://reports.cucumber.io/reports/eec74059-cf30-4771-85ea-5e12779d2629

the problem i want to share the link to slack, how do i get the link from command line ? thank you